APPIUM 2.5.2 - Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command
Code:
`import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.time.Duration;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;


public class AppTest 
{
    //public AndroidDriver driver;
    //public AppiumDriverLocalService service;

@Test

    public void AppiumTest() throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException
    {
        //AndroidDriver , IOSDriver
        //Appium code --> Appium server --> Mobile
        
        //run appium server automatically
       AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(new File("\\Users\\michal.tomanek\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
          .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).build();
       service.start();    
        
       
        //Create capabilities
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setDeviceName("Amazone_emulator");
        options.setPlatformVersion("13");
        options.setApp("\\Users\\michal.tomanek\\eclipse-workspace\\mySprayer\\src\\test\\java\\Resources\\de.amazone.iom.mysprayer-DEMO.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "ANDROID" );
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "de.amazone.iom.mysprayer");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "crc647be385f51bfe3f27.MainActivity");

        
        //create object for android driver
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URI("http://127.0.0.1:4723").toURL(), options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    
        //Actual automation
        //Xpath, id, accessibilityIs, classname, androidUIAutomator
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.Switch")).click();
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.widget.Switch")).click();
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text=\"Continue\"]")).click();

        
        driver.quit();
        service.stop();
    }   
                
}`

Appium logs:
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@68bd (5e3d6f5d)][0m Starting 'de.amazone.iom.mysprayer/crc647be385f51bfe3f27.SplashActivity and waiting for 'de.amazone.iom.mysprayer/crc647be385f51bfe3f27.SplashActivity'
[38;5;48m[ADB][0m Running 'C:\Users\michal.tomanek\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n de.amazone.iom.mysprayer/crc647be385f51bfe3f27.SplashActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000'
[38;5;32m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@68bd (5e3d6f5d)][0m Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"4173d4af-2e4c-4e83-b2fa-2c052999e551","value":{"androidId":"c3ef959451134228","apiVersion":"33","bluetooth":{"state":"ON"},"brand":"google","carrierName":"T-Mobile","displayDensity":440,"locale":"en_US","manufacturer":"Google","model":"sdk_gphone64_x86_64","networks":[{"capabilities":{"SSID":null,"linkDownBandwidthKbps":4300,"linkUpstreamBandwidthKbps":1800,"networkCapabilities":"NET_CAPABILITY_MMS,NET_CAPABILITY_SUPL,NET_CAPABILITY_DUN,NET_CAPABILITY_FOTA,NET_CAPABILITY_IMS,NET_CAPABILITY_CBS,NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED,NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN,NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_ROAMING,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_CONGESTED,NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_SUSPENDED","signalStrength":-2147483648,"transportTypes":"TRANSPORT_CELLULAR"},"detailedState":"CONNECTED","extraInfo":"epc.tmobile.com","isAvailable":true,"isConnected":true,"isFailover":false,"isRoaming":false,"state":"CONNECTED","subtype":10,"subtypeName":"HSPA","type":0,"typeName":"MOBILE"},{"capabiliti...
[38;5;96m[Instrumentation][0m io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test.AppiumUiAutomator2Server:
[38;5;48m[ADB][0m Waiting up to 20000ms for activity matching pkg: 'de.amazone.iom.mysprayer' and activity: 'crc647be385f51bfe3f27.SplashActivity' to be focused
[38;5;48m[ADB][0m Possible activities, to be checked: 'crc647be385f51bfe3f27.SplashActivity', 'de.amazone.iom.mysprayer.crc647be385f51bfe3f27.SplashActivity'
[38;5;48m[ADB][0m Getting focused package and activity
[38;5;48m[ADB][0m Running 'C:\Users\michal.tomanek\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell dumpsys window displays'
[38;5;48m[ADB][0m Found package: 'de.amazone.iom.mysprayer' and fully qualified activity name : 'crc647be385f51bfe3f27.MainActivity'
[38;5;48m[ADB][0m Incorrect package and activity. Retrying.

FAILED: AMAZONE.mySprayer.AppTest.AppiumTest
**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'de.amazone.iom.mysprayer' application. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. Original error: 'crc647be385f51bfe3f27.SplashActivity' or 'de.amazone.iom.mysprayer.crc647be385f51bfe3f27.SplashActivity' never started. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. **
Host info: host: 'HW000747', ip: '172.30.224.1'
Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '21.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:app: \Users\michal.tomanek\eclip..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Amazone_emulator, appium:platformVersion: 13, platformName: ANDROID}, capabilities=[{appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, platformName=ANDROID, appium:app=\Users\michal.tomanek\eclipse-workspace\mySprayer\src\test\java\Resources\de.amazone.iom.mysprayer-DEMO.apk, appium:platformVersion=13, appium:deviceName=Amazone_emulator}]}]
Capabilities {appium:app: \Users\michal.tomanek\eclip..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Amazone_emulator, appium:platformVersion: 13, platformName: ANDROID}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:114)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:116)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:96)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:176)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:237)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:161)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:90)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:109)
    at AMAZONE.mySprayer.AppTest.AppiumTest(AppTest.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:228)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:961)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:201)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:293)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:91)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

What is happening
I would be pleased if anyone has a solution for this issue. App was launched (splash activity) in emulator and then MainActivity follows, but something was wrong and there is still repeating "Incorrect package and activity. Retrying" and that sth with package and activity is not right, but via app info I got appPackage and appActivity and it is correct.
**  cap.setCapability("appPackage", "de.amazone.iom.mysprayer");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "crc647be385f51bfe3f27.MainActivity");**
So I am not able to proceed to actual automation, even screen is loaded. I would be more than thankful for any advice.

What is this random string before .MainActivity? Remove it and it should work

Make sure the appPackage and appActivity you are using is valid one. Alternate way is to provide android apk file in DesiredCapabilities instead of appPackage and appActivity.
